# plotting using a for loop

Tags: r, plot

I want to plot a number of graph using this for loop. however, I can only get one output (foo0001).

```
for (i in 1:5) {
 bitmap("foo%03d.jpg")
 plot(runif(20), ylim = c(0, 1))
 dev.off()
}
```

please help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`bitmap` writes each page (plot) to consecutive files according to the format string chosen. Calling `bitmap` creates a new graphics device, resetting the page number. So, by plotting one plot per `bitmap` call, you are always writing to `foo0001.jpg`.

Instead, call `bitmap` just once:

```
bitmap("foo%03d.jpg")
for (i in 1:5) {
     plot(runif(20), ylim = c(0, 1))
}
dev.off()
```

Comment: wow, it works! 
This is my first time to ask question here.
I'm so happy to get reply so quick. 
 
Thank you sooo much!